# jQuery Remove multiple classes on page if 2nd child is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove multiple classes on one page if 2nd child within an element is empty. I can get it to work with one but not all classes are being removed.

If .dropwraptext is empty then the entire .dropwrap should be removed.

The html:

```
      <dl class="toggle clearfix">
     <div class="dropwrap">
 <dt><span><em class="fa fa-plus"></em></span>Title 1</dt>
 <dd class="dropwraptext"><ul>Content 1</ul></dd>
      </div>  

     <div class="dropwrap">
 <dt><span><em class="fa fa-plus"></em></span>Title 2</dt>
 <dd class="dropwraptext"><ul></ul></dd>
</div>  

<div class="dropwrap">
 <dt><span><em class="fa fa-plus"></em></span>Title 3</dt>
 <dd class="dropwraptext"><ul></ul></dd>
</div>   

 <div class="dropwrap">
 <dt><span><em class="fa fa-plus"></em></span>Title 4</dt>
 <dd class="dropwraptext"><ul>content4</ul></dd>
</div>   

            </dl>
```

The JS:

```
     $('.dropwraptext ul:empty').parents().eq(1).remove();
```

View in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UNZTV/17/

You will notice that title 2 should be removed but is still showing.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to remove classes or elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're selecting the second one in the collection only with `eq(1)`, remove that

```
$('.dropwraptext ul:empty').closest('.dropwrap').remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UNZTV/19/)